# matching an address with regex doesn't match the target part

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I'm not quite good in regex.

With my input string `LT 1 BLK 4 LAKES OF PARKWAY 5 R/P & AMEND`

I'd like to match just the only part between the figure `4` and `5` in the string.

meaning that, my expected result is `LAKES OF PARKWAY`.

I've tried to come up with a pattern to get such result.

```
 \d+\s+([A-z ]+)(\d+.*?)*$
```

but with my pattern, it only matches `BLK` and `5 R/P & AMEND`, as group #1 and group #2 respectively. At the end of my thought pattern, I decide to use end of string matching, `$`.
So, when `5 R/P & AMEND` got matched, the pointer should move further behind to the sub sequence part. Then, `([A-z ]+)` should match `LAKES OF PARKWAY`.

What's wrong with my pattern? and how to get it to work?

Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This _looks_ like PCRE, but can you tell us the language or library you're using so we can be sure we know which syntax your answer should be in? There are many different, incompatible regex forms (for instance, POSIX BRE is what grep uses by default, and POSIX ERE is used in many other standard tools).

Comment: ...by the way, what `[A-z]` means is dependent on your locale; it's not a safe thing to use. If you want `[[:alpha:][:space:]]`, that's possible (though exactly how it's written depends on which regex form).

Comment: Thanks Charles. I'm using Regex in Ruby on Rails. Is it PCRE?

Comment: Ruby's regexes are... similar to PCRE, though they have some extensions I've never seen before, and I haven't checked whether they implement full compatibility with PCRE syntax. It probably wouldn't hurt, in the future, to specify that's what you're using when asking a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `\d+\s+(\D+)\d+\D*$`

`\D` means 'anything that is not `\d`, so it won't be allowed to match, for example, between the first 1 and 4, because then the ending of the regex would be rejected at the later `5`.